# How to make Cordova/web element size adjust to Android device font size

Tags: android, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic / Cordova application where I have a, list of element which I would like all the same height. When I run this on an Android device (in this case a Pixel 3A running Android 12), with setting with default font size, my items all look the correct height.

However, it I set the font size to say large, eg..

[image]

the item is not high enough to contain all the all the text (it has 4 divs of text)

[image]

I set using `rem` instead of `px` which should look at the font size but this does not help.

How can I make this adjust taking into account the phones font size, and why rem does not work?

### Update

A bit more info as request in a comment...

The element in question looks like the following (is inside a list of these items)

```
  <div tappable class='card-inner' (click)='clickCard(item)'>
    <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>            
        <ion-col>
          <div class='card-text'><b>{{item0.description}}</b></div>
          <div class='card-text'>{{item1.description}}</div>
          <div class='card-text'>{{item2.description}}</div>
          <div class='card-text'>{{item.2.description}}
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
```

In global.scss I have

```
.card-inner {
   box-shadow: var(--card-inner-box-shadow) !important;
   border-radius: 1px;
   padding: 1px;
   margin: 3px;
   vertical-align: top;
 }
.card-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

An in the component CSS, where I set this height I have

```
.card-inner {
   height: 5.75rem;
 }
```

If I remove the `height: 5.75rem;` the cards DO size to the connect height, however some may have one or more row of text not set, so they are different (shorter) heights. I want all the same height, and the `height: 5.75rem;` does this and look right everywhere except when I have the Android large fonts set.. I would have thought this increased the size of a root font, so the `rem` would work.

Unfortunately I just cannot view the app running on my device using `chrome://inspect/#devices` like use to work for me (another thing I need to look into at another time).

Comment: You will need to include relevant css

Comment: @Suraj I have added some more information on the elements and the css. Most is just a bit of styling, it is just the `height` that I seem to have the issue with here